# how to display customized values on a bar in bar chart using jfree chart?

Tags: jfreechart

By using StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator() Iam able to display the exact range axis value on a bar, Now my problem is I dont want to display the range axis value instead I want to display some other value of that bar How I can achieve that?

```
for (String IDS : idMap.keySet()) {
    List<String> listValues = idMap.get(IDS);
    if(listValues != null && listValues.get(1) != null) {
       dataSet.setValue(Double.valueOf(listValues.get(1)), "", IDS);
    }
}
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("", "", "Time taken ", dataSet,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
chart.setTitle(new org.jfree.chart.title.TextTitle("Time Duration",new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 10)));
chart.getLegend().setItemFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif",0,7));
chart.removeLegend();
final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
plot.setNoDataMessage("No data available");
final CategoryItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setItemLabelsVisible(true);
final BarRenderer r = (BarRenderer) renderer;
r.setMaximumBarWidth(0.05);
r.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
r.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
r.setSeriesItemLabelFont(0, new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman",Font.NORMAL,7));
r.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(0,     
                    new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE3, TextAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT, TextAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT, -Math.PI/2));
final ValueAxis rangeAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setLabelFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 8));
final CategoryAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
axis.setLabel("ids");
axis.setLabelFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 8));
axis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 8.0));
axis.setTickLabelFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 6));
plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(true);
```

By using the above code iam able to display exact range axis value on a bar, but I dont want the range axis value I need some other value listValues.get(2) to be displayed on a bar How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator` uses an instance of `MessgeFormat` for this, defaulting to *ArgumentIndex* `{2}`. The other *ArgumentIndex* values are [defined](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/a362a41d4d944f6be5d3ec2f93c32bc975e10c0b/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/labels/AbstractCategoryItemLabelGenerator.java#L66) in the abstract parent. For example,

```
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(
    new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator(
        "{0} {1} {2} {3}", NumberFormat.getInstance()));
renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
```

You can also override `generateLabel()` to return any value you want.

Comment: Please edit your question to include revised code as an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: sorry for above comment. Actually generateLabelString() accepts dataset,row,column as parameters how I can pass listValues.get(2) to display listValues.get(2) on the bar.

Comment: Can you pass the map as a parameter to your generator's constructor and look up the second value.

Comment: thanks trashgod I have overrided generateLabel() method in StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator() and achieved what I want to display.

Comment: @satish: Yes, overriding `generateLabel()` is the better choice; updated.

Answer (score 4):

```
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(
new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator()
 @Override
 public String generateLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, int row, int column) {
        return "Your Text" +row+","+column;
 }
);
```