# JFreeChart | How to add percentage to top of each bar and format domain axis (X axis) ticklabels?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) and following is a screenshot of the developed chart by me and the related code.

[image: JFreeChart]

```
    private void getBarChart(List<Data> data) {
JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("", "", "", createDataset(data), PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
        CategoryPlot plot = barChart.getCategoryPlot();
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(7, 43, 97));

        barChart.getCategoryPlot().getRangeAxis().setLowerBound(0);
        barChart.getCategoryPlot().getRangeAxis().setUpperBound(1);
        NumberAxis xAxis2 = (NumberAxis) barChart.getCategoryPlot().getRangeAxis();
        xAxis2.setNumberFormatOverride(NumberFormat.getPercentInstance());

        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesItemLabelGenerator(0, new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(1, true);
        plot.getRenderer().setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
        plot.getRenderer().setBaseSeriesVisible(true);
        barChart.getCategoryPlot().setRenderer(plot.getRenderer());


        BarRenderer.setDefaultBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
        ((BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer()).setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(650, 250, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(JFreeChart.KEY_SUPPRESS_SHADOW_GENERATION, true);
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 650, 250);
        barChart.draw(g2, r);
        BufferedImage chartImage = barChart.createBufferedImage(600, 400, null);
}
```

The expected chart should be something like following.
[image]

**Question 1.)** **How to format the x axis lables as per like the expected graph ?**(CategoryLables or TickLabels in barChart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis())

**Question 2.)** The values displayed in top of each bar (SeriesItemLabels) needs to be formatted with a percentage mark(%) similar to the y axis. (Also I think, like I have done in xAxis2.setNumberFormatOverride, the values will automatically get multipled by 100%. Right now it displays the decimal value only). How to achieve this ?

Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The following line enables the axis-labels with an ascending slope:

```
CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();  
domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_45);
```

45 denotes the angle in degree and UP means an orientation from bottom left to top right. You can also define an arbitrary angle (e.g. 22.5°) with

```
CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();  
domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.toRadians(22.5)));
```

It should be noted that `createUpRotationLabelPositions` expects an angle in radians.

2) The following line formats the bar-labels of series 0 in percent.

```
DecimalFormat labelFormat = new DecimalFormat("##0.0 %");
labelFormat.setMultiplier(100);
plot.getRenderer().setSeriesItemLabelGenerator(0, new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{2}", labelFormat));
plot.getRenderer().setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(0, true);
```

with {0} = series, {1} = category, {2} = value

As an alternative you can define your own label generator, e.g.:

```
class CstmStandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator extends StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator {

    @Override
    public String generateLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, int row, int column) {
        return String.format("%.1f %%", dataset.getValue(row, column).doubleValue() * 100.0);
    }
}
```

which simply can be used as follows:

```
plot.getRenderer().setSeriesItemLabelGenerator(0, new CstmStandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 4):

Working from [`BarChartDemo1.java`](https://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/3111/tree/branches/jfreechart-1.0.x-branch/source/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java#l28), updated for [JFreechart 1.5](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart), the following alternative are illustrated below.

1. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12184526/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964999/230513), you can invoke `setCategoryLabelPositions()` on the domain axis and use `CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions` to fine-tune the angle. The example below rotates counter-clockwise π/4 radians or 45°.

   ```
   CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
   domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(
       CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 4.0));
   ```
2. A shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13627138/230513), you can construct a custom `StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator`, but you may want to use *ArgumentIndex* [`{3}`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/a362a41d4d944f6be5d3ec2f93c32bc975e10c0b/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/labels/AbstractCategoryItemLabelGenerator.java#L66), which is the value as a percentage of the column total, as well as a suitable `NumberFormat`.

   ```
   renderer.setDefaultItemLabelGenerator(
       new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator(
           "{3}", NumberFormat.getPercentInstance()));
   renderer.setDefaultItemLabelsVisible(true);
   ```

[image: bar chart]