# JFreeChart background color setting is not respected

Tags: jfreechart

In JFreeChart I used to generate the chart with *CategoryDataset* and with *createLineChart*. This looked like this:

[image]

Due to some axis changes I had to switch to *XYLineAndShapeRenderer*, and now the chart looks like this:
[image]

Please notice the gray area around the chart. I want to change it to transparent or at least white just like it was on the old one above.

I tried doing it by:

```
chart.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
```

But it does not work.

How can I change that background to white, and change the plot's background to gray (just like it was on the old one?)

Thanks!

## UPDATE

I can update the plot's background, but not the ChartPanel's.

Here is the diagram which has these options:

```
lineChart.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint(Color.red);
chartPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
```

[image]

Here I would like to have the yellow as the background of the chartPanel.

Comment: The temperature demo shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57544811/230513) has those colors by default; the factory applies the standard chart theme.

Comment: Is it possible that they looks different on different OSes? These shots are taken from a Tomcat web server.

Comment: Yes, or different chart themes or different versions of the [tag:jfreechart) library itself; note also that the chart and plot can have different background paints.

Comment: Okay, so at the point when I change from _CategoryPlot_ to _XYPlot_ along with _XYLineAndShapeRenderer_ the background colors change as shown in the question. So it is still valid: how can I ask _XYPlot_ to have a gray background?

Comment: To be more exact I've updated the Q.

Comment: Okay, it was a user error. The gray area was not the chartPanel, but the JFreeChart itself, so background can be set by _lineChart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.pink);_

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a user error. The gray area around the plot was not the `ChartPanel` but the `JFreeChart` itself. The chart and plot backgrounds can be set separately, for example:

```
lineChart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.pink);
plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.cyan.darker());
```

A complete example for testing is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57633234/230513).

[image: background colors]