# JFreechart chart with Time from SQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, charts, jfreechart

I'm new with JFreeChart and I'm trying to create a chart that display a value on the y-axis and the time on the x-axis.
All theses data (value and time) are already in my database and I have something like a value for each 3 to 4 seconds.

However I do not want to display everything or to be dynamic. I just want to display a chart that shows all the values from 2020-06-16 10:31:52 to 2020-06-29 11:31:52 for example (but everything is already in my Database as I said).

Here is my variation of this (without all the imports) :

```
public class JDBCTest {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("JDBCTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JDBCXYDataset jds = createDataset();
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            "Inventory", "Date", "Count", jds, true, true, false);
        f.add(new ChartPanel(chart));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JDBCXYDataset createDataset() {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:","", "");
           
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test ");
            st.execute("create table Test(Date_Heure timestamp, PV float)");
            
            String Date_Debut = "2020-06-25 13:28:08";
            String Date_Fin = "2020-06-26 13:28:08";
            String sql1 = "INSERT INTO Test (Date_Heure,PV) "
                    + "SELECT TABLE ,TABLE "
                    + "FROM TABLE "
                    + "WHERE Date_Heure BETWEEN ? AND ?";
            
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
           
            ps.setString(1,Date_Debut);
            ps.setString(2,Date_Fin);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            
            JDBCXYDataset jds = new JDBCXYDataset(conn);
            jds.executeQuery("select TABLE , TABLE from Test");
            return jds;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
            return null;
        }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JDBCTest().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT : The error was comming from the Database and not from the code itself.

---

Edit :
The code is inspired around trashgod's work http://stackoverflow.com/a/24762078/230513

additional information :

`Date_Time` type's `timestamp`

`PV` type's `float`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [example cited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24762078/230513) using [`JDBCXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCXYDataset.html) also works with [`JDBCCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCCategoryDataset.html), as shown below and in your original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63917976/1). Using `JDBCCategoryDataset`, "The first column will be the category name and [the] remaining columns [will be] values (each column represents a series);" using `JDBCXYDataset`, "The first column will be the x-axis and remaining columns y-axis values. " As a result, I would expect your query to be something like this:

```
SELECT Date_Time, PV …
```

As your domain axis is time, consider rotating the label positions, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57544811/230513). When deciding, note that a `TimeSeries` is less flexible about orientation but more flexible about formatting.

[image]

> the values in my database are `Float`.

The following changes to the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24762078/230513) illustrate using floating point values.  Note that `PV` is of type `float`, and the `PreparedStatement` uses `setFloat()`.

```
JDBCCategoryDataset jds = createDataset();
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Test", "Time", "PV",
    jds,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
CategoryAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
plot.getDomainAxis().setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_45);
…
private JDBCCategoryDataset createDataset() {
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:h2:mem:test", "", "");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.execute("create table data(when timestamp, pv float)");
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
            "insert into data values (?, ?)");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(c.getTimeInMillis()));
            ps.setFloat(2, (float)r.nextGaussian() + 2);
            ps.execute();
            c.add(Calendar.SECOND, r.nextInt(60 * 60));
        }
        JDBCCategoryDataset jds = new JDBCCategoryDataset(conn);
        jds.executeQuery("select when, pv from data");
        return jds;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: One of my biggest problem is that the values in my database are `Float` and represented like this in my DB : [![2.png](https://i.postimg.cc/pyNpcxrV/2.png)](https://postimg.cc/rRJVzB57) 
But I don't know how to use them like in your exemple because everytime I try they are converted to `int` ( I suppose ) so when I try do display the graph the value are way off...

Comment: @Nemrod: I've update the answer; instead of images, please edit your question to show the `PV` attribute's type.

Comment: Thanks a lot @trashgod, your exemple is great but I get random values with it, how do I do to use and display the values that I already have in my database instead of generating randoms values ?

Comment: I also edited my question to be more actual and with my new issue, please check it out, It may be more understandable :)

Comment: It looks like using the correct selection order and switching to `JDBCXYDataset` solves your JFreeChart problem. The anomalies in your data may warrant a new question, but you can try using  an `ORDER BY` clause to see if you have duplicate timestamps..

Comment: It's seems like the query is executed twice ( I do have duplicate timestamps ) but I don't know where the problem is comming from ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956674/query-executed-twice-by-error-in-java-with-unwanted-values