# Query executed twice (by error) in Java with unwanted values

Tags: java, mysql, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart to create a chart in Java and MySQL.

When I try to insert my values in another table the query seems to be executed twice since I end up with the same timestamps multiple times...

Here's a part of my code :

```
    private JDBCXYDataset createDataset() {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:bd?serverTimezone=UTC","MySQL", "MySQL");
           
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            SQLException savedException = null;
            
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test ");
            st.execute("create table test(Table timestamp, Table float,Table float)");
            
            String Date_Debut = "2020-06-25 00:00:00";
            String Date_Fin = "2020-06-26 00:00:00";
            String sql1 = "INSERT INTO test (Table ,Table ,Table ) "
                    + "SELECT Table ,Table ,Table "
                    + "FROM Table "
                    + "WHERE Table BETWEEN ? AND ? ";
            
           try ( PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql1)){
           
            ps.setString(1,Date_Debut);
            ps.setString(2, Date_Fin);
         
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
            
            JDBCXYDataset jds = new JDBCXYDataset(conn);
            
            st.close();
            
            jds.executeQuery("SELECT Table ,Table ,Table FROM test");
            
            
            conn.commit();
            return jds;
           } catch (SQLException ex) {
               savedException = ex;
               conn.rollback();
           } finally {
               conn.setAutoCommit(true);
               if(savedException != null) {
                   throw savedException;
               }
           }
       } catch (SQLException ex1) {
           
       }
        return null;
    }
```

EDIT : Actually it seems like the errors where comming directly from the database, the moderators can delete this post if they want. However I keep Trashgod's response validated as it was more than helpful.
For everyone that might come here with a similar issue, inspect in detail your database first to see if it isn't comming from there instead of your code.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I've checked and also with how "cmd3" is working it's impossible to have twice the same timestamp as it's based on current time. I tried to add unique to my new table but as I said it only keep the unwanted values and not the one I'm supposed to get, which is weird I agree but I don't know how tp fix it.
( it was an answer to somebody before he deleted his comment, I will keep it to add some detail )

Comment: You are not doing ps.executeUpdate, nor closing statements and result sets. Closing is important, use try-with-resources (commits etc.). But my first guess was a bug with JDBCXYDataset jds.

Comment: @JoopEggen I edited my post with what you said, is it how you thought about it ? If it is then it doesn't work better unfortunately....
Ps : My images have been deleted.... that makes my post less understandable but I guess I don't have a choice.

Comment: Yes, in principle the usage of the prepared statement is better. Maybe there is still some answer coming.

Comment: @Nemrod: nothing is lost; see the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63956674/revisions) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chasing down anomalies in data is arduous, but `JFreeChart` can at least make the result easier to visualize. Some heuristics for testing:

- To verify that the the presumed duplicates in your tabular listing  are indeed duplicates, format the timestamps to include milliseconds, e.g. add an `S` to a `SimpleDateFormat` or `A` to a `DateTimeFormatter`.
- For study, temporarily pass the query directly to `JDBCXYDataset`, and add an `ORDER BY` clause (untested):

  ```
  jds.executeQuery(
        "SELECT Date_Heure, PV, SV FROM cmd3 "
      + "WHERE Date_Heure BETWEEN "
      + "2020-06-25 00:00:00 AND 2020-06-26 00:00:00 "
      + "ORDER BY Date_Heure");
  ```
- Enable tooltips in your `ChartFactory`, as you did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63917976/230513), to see data values *in situ*. This may suggest additional conditions for your `WHERE` clause, e.g. `PV BETWEEN 5.1 AND 5.9`.
- Use the interactive `JFreeChart` pan/zoom controls, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44151032/230513) to examine the data; add suitable buttons, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41544007/230513), if it will make it easier for colleagues to see your findings.
- By design, [`JDBCXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCXYDataset.html) executes a query defined by a `String`. If your design needs to display data from a query defined by a `PreparedStatement`, you can use the existing [implementation](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCXYDataset.java) as a guide.

  ```
  public class PreparedDataset extends AbstractXYDataset
      implements XYDataset, TableXYDataset, RangeInfo {

      private final PreparedStatement ps;

      public PreparedDataset(PreparedStatement ps) {
          this.ps = ps;
      }
      …
  }
  ```