# Change color of item labels on range on Category chart

Tags: bar-chart, jfreechart

I want to change the color of labels showing in black, but I am unable to find a solution.

I tried using below code, but it has no effect

```
CategoryAxis yaxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
yaxis.setLabelPaint(Color.WHITE);
```

I want to change the font color of range and category.

[image]

Comment: The category item labels in your image appear nearly white. Do you want them to be black or white?

Answer (score 1):

Given a category chart that has a `CategoryItemLabelGenerator`, such as the [`BarChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo2/BarChartDemo1.java) variation cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68987663/230513).

- You can change the color used by the renderer for the item labels, illustrated below with white labels on a gray background:

  ```
    CategoryItemLabelGenerator generator =
        new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator(…);
    renderer.setDefaultItemLabelGenerator(generator);
    renderer.setDefaultItemLabelPaint(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setDefaultItemLabelsVisible(true);
  ```
- You can change the axis label color using `setLabelPaint()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjfreechart%5D%20setLabelPaint).
- You can change the axis tick mark color using `setTickMarkPaint()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14262284/230513).

[image]